# Distinguishable Objects into Indistinguishable boxes

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to work through a problem that states "$2n+1$ employees must be placed into 2 indistinguishable offices", and I want to know how many different ways that I can achieve this. I know that there is no closed form solution for distinguishable objects into indistinguishable boxes, but I'm having trouble even starting the problem given that I do not even have a concrete number of employees that I'm solving this problem for. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

UPDATE:

I have attempted this problem in 2 ways now with almost identical answers. The question now is which would be correct and why.

The first way I attempt it is by initially considering the offices to be distinguishable. If this is the case, then I know the number of ways that I can but $n$ distinguishable objects into $k$ distinguishable boxes is $k^n$ ways. In this case, I'd have $2^{2n+1}$ different ways. Since the offices are indistinguishable though, I will divide out a 2. I do this because when I wrote out the different combinations for 3 and 5 employees (the smallest two numbers of employees when $n=1$ and $n=2$) I notice that there is a pattern that repeats among the two offices. If they are indistinguishable, then this would result in duplicate configurations which dividing by 2 should eliminate. Therefore, my final result is $\frac{2^{2n+1}}{2} = 2^{2n}$ combinations.

The second way that I attempted is with Stirling numbers of the second order. The formula that I used was $\frac{1}{j!} \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} (-1)^i {j\choose i} (j-i)^n$ where $j$ is the number of offices and $n$ is the number of employees. Therefore, if $i$ starts at 0 and goes to $j-1=1$, then I can hand calculate the two values of the equation for $i=0$ and $i=1$ and solve. For $i=0$ the equation results in $\frac{2^{2n+1}}{2} = 2^{2n}$, a good sign. For $i=1$, the equation results in -1. When I sum these, I get $2^{2n}-1$, which is slightly different. What I think I might be misunderstanding is how the upper bound of the summation works, in that I do not actually have to calculate for $i=1$, which would explain why the answers are different by 1 digit. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What information do they want about this?

Comment: Presumably the question, which you have not actually stated, is, "how many ways can this be done?" Would you be able to answer it, if the boxes were distinguishable? And then can you see what difference it makes that the boxes are indistinguishable?

Comment: For the first comment, I want to know how many different combinations there are for this, aka how many ways can this be done as @GerryMyerson stated. I suppose that if the boxes were also distinguishable, I would take a permutation of P(2n+1, 2) which would result in $\frac{(2n+1)!}{(2n-1)!2!}$. I guess I still don't see the connection though if the offices were indistinguishable.

Comment: $P(2n+1,2)$ is the number of permutations of $2n+1$ things taken $2$ at a time. But you're not taking two things, are you? Maybe you should take some small value of $n$, like $n=1$ or $n=2$, and write out all the different ways, and see how many you get, and think about why you get that many.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah I'm starting to see. For distinguishable offices, if I start with $n=1$, then I ultimately have $2^3$ ways to arrange the 3 workers into the 2 offices. If I take $n=2$, I have $2^5$ ways to arrange the 5 workers into the 2 offices. So my guess would be that if the offices were no longer distinguishable, I would simply divide my results by 2, since if I look at what I wrote out, I see patterns that repeat between the distinguishable offices that would be repetitions if they were indistinguishable. Is this on the right track?

Comment: Looks good to me, bpryan. Let me encourage you to post it as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Please check out my update to my post and see if you agree!

Comment: The first way is correct.  (I don't quite understand your second way so no comment there.)  You can also think of it this way: the first employee (CEO? founder? janitor?) must be in some office, and then the other $2n$ employees can independently decide to join the first employee or not, so there are $2^{2n}$ ways.

Comment: @antkam I think I see the discrepancy. My problem specifies that there can be an empty offices, which makes $2^{2n}$ correct, and why the Stirling numbers of the second kind yields the result $2^{2n}-1$: This equation assumes that no 'box' (or office in this case) is empty. Therefore, the Stirling equation can be used but in this case, there is the extra possibility of an empty office, so we add 1.

Answer (score 0):

Stirling numbers of second kind can be applied in distributing distinguishable objects into indistinguishable blocks but in this case two offices can not be treated as indistinguishable blocks. There is another point in your case all can be put into one block and there are 2 different cases for that only. These cases are not included in Stirling numbers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that the offices are indistinguishable.  Therefore, there is only one way to place all the people in one office.

Comment: @ Taussig, you are quite right according to the conditions stated in the question .